# PyQt - Automatically refresh a custom view when the model is updated?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt4, pyqt

By default, the built-in views in PyQt can auto-refresh itself when its model has been updated. I wrote my own chart view, but I don't know how to do it, I have to manually update it for many times.

Which signal should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect your view to the `dataChanged ( const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight )` signal of the model:

> This signal is emitted whenever the data in an existing item changes.
>
> If the items are of the same parent, the affected ones are those
>   between topLeft and bottomRight inclusive. If the items do not have
>   the same parent, the behavior is undefined.
>
> When reimplementing the setData() function, this signal must be
>   emitted explicitly.

Comment: With `QTableView()` , if I `setModel(model)`, `setQuery(sql)`, then `setQuery(another_sql)`, the view will auto refresh. How can my view do the same thing?

Comment: your view is deriving from `QAbstractItemView`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It is a wrapper of matplotlib widget.

Comment: Maybe I need to implement more. Which signal has been emited when `setQuery()` executed?

Comment: when the model emits the `dataChanged` signal the views `dataChanged` slot is called, you should implement it in your view

Comment: Okay, I will implement `dataChanged` slot. I also have another strange issue about `dataChanged`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001592/pyqt-qtableview-doesnt-respond-datachanged-signal

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the index() object from model , you can call the data changed signal from the model or outside the model, if you call from the model, follow the next step:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
```

some models functions can get the index,for example:

```
def setData(self, **index**, value)
```

so, you can call the signal:

```
def setData(self, index, value):
   #do something

   self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
```

The index on the signal indicates which element changed its data
If you want to change, refresh or reload data **from outside the model** and you do not have the index, it is not necessary to indicate which element will be changed, so, you can apply the next line

```
self.yourmodel.dataChanged.emit(QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex())
```

This will refresh all the data that has changed.